# jqGrid with multiselect how to check all checkboxes and top one at load?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I instruct jqGrid to directly select all checkboxes when I instantiate it? Can this be done as a parameter in the colModel somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the

```
$('.cbox').click();
```

in the `gridComplete` but that didn't work. Then I tried this:

```
$('.cbox').attr('checked', true);
```

and that worked, it set all checkboxes to checked but what happened then is that I needed to click twice to uncheck one.

What worked for me was:

```
$('.cbox').trigger('click');
```

Comment: $('.cbox').click() and $('.cbox').trigger('click') should do the same thing.

Comment: @Daniel, I tried your solution but for some reason that did not work. Do not know why.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solutions above but it would not select the checkboxes. This Solved the problem.

`$('.cbox').trigger('click').attr('checked', true);`

Fixes the issue of checking boxes and you only have to click on it once to uncheck.

Make sure you do this after the jqgrid has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at setSelection. From [jqGrid Documentation](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm)

```
setSelection(rowid, onsetselection)
Toggles a selection of the row with id = rowid; if onsetselection is true (the default) then the event onSetRow is launched, otherwise it is not
```

Another way you can do this is by marking all checkboxes int the grid:

```
$('.cbox').click();
```

But you want to call this after the grid is complete, so call it inside gridComplete event:

```
    gridComplete: function() {
      $('.cbox').click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will select all rows. It follows many of the same suggestions made by Daniel:

```
gridSelectAll : function(divID){
    // Select header checkbox (no jqGrid API for this, unfortunately)
    var parentView = divID.replace("#", "#gview_");
    jQuery(parentView).find("#cb_jqg").click();

    // Loop again to select all rows
    var data = jQuery(divID).getDataIDs();
    for(var i=0; i < data.length;i++){
        jQuery(divID).setSelection(data[i]); // All selected by default
    }
}
```

You can call this from the GridComplete event to automatically check all of the boxes at load time.