# jQuery and jqxGrid - how to select all rows in jqxGrid via checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

How can I check all rows of  jQWidgets jqxGrid with checkbox options programmatically‎? I can loop through rows and select them one-by-one or use

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('selectallrows');
```

but I need to make a selection via the checkbox option - see

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?%28arctic%29#demos/jqxgrid/checkboxselection.htm

Basically I need to replicate a click on the top "Select All" checkbox.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: check that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028729/jqgrid-with-multiselect-how-to-check-all-checkboxes-and-top-one-at-load

Comment: Thanks, but that thread is for jqGrid - not for jqxGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
$('#jqxGrid').jqxGrid('selectallrows');
```

Comment: Yes, it selects all rows and their checkboxes, but not the header box "Select All". Something weird, because to deselect all rows we would need to click twice on the header box.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution:

```
$('#jqxGrid').jqxGrid({ selectionmode: 'checkbox'});
```

This will add a new column at the beginning for the checkboxes and a box for 'checkall' action.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
var rows = $('#grid').jqxGrid('getRows');
for(var i = 0 ; i < rows.length ; i++){
    var _item = rows[i];
    $('#grid').jqxGrid('setcellvaluebyid', _item.boundindex, "[YOUR COLUMN]", true);
}//for end(i)
```